# Is there a way to make a for loop that will get one element of the data in every iteration and create a vector at the end of all the elements

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a sql database with ID's and info, I want to loop through the database and only get info for certain IDs, I want to get an element of every info of every ID in the database and store it into a vector.

I have tried a for loop, but get only the ID numbers.

```r
a <-c()
for (i in IDs){

  x <- dbGetQuery(mydb, paste('SELECT * FROM  table WHERE Person = ', i, ';'))
  info = fromJSON(x$info)

  ind <- as.data.frame(info$x)
  int <- as.data.frame(info$y)
  inx <- as.data.frame(info$z)

  a[i] <- inx[,5][1]
}
```

The expected output would be a vector of elements that correspond to the element that is in inx column 5 for every ID in the vector I'm iterating. So a vector of length of the IDs desired that contains one element for each ID.

Comment: I think you could drop the for loop and just use "IN" in your SQL statement.  Something like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Person IN(123, 234, 345)"

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Anyways, for a start, you need to get query out of the loop. Use this - `options(useFancyQuotes = F);
ID_string <- paste(sQuote(IDs), collapse = ", ");
x <- dbGetQuery(mydb, paste0('SELECT * FROM  table WHERE Person IN (', ID_string, ');'))`